# Comparing string including decimal in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I have question here:

How do I compare variable that has string+decimal in Python.
Example :

```
a = "2.11.22-abc-def-ghi"

if a == (2.11*) :
print "ok"
```

I want it only compare the first 2 decimal point only and it doesn't care the rest of it value. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to be more specific. There are many way to approach this and not sure which one is the one to go.. If you want to know if the strings starts with `2.11`, take a look at `str.startswith`. If you want to know if `2.11` is anywhere in the string, just use `'2.11' in a`. If you want to look for a specific pattern in the string where, in a specific location, the value is `2.11`, take a look at regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the most direct answer to your question, I think...a way to code what your pseudocode is getting at:

```
a = "2.11.22-abc-def-ghi"

if a.startswith("2.11"):
    print("ok")
```

If you want to grab the numeric value off the front, turn it into a true number, and use that in a comparison, no matter what the specific value, you could do this:

```
import re

a = "2.11.22-abc-def-ghi"

m = re.match(r"(\d+\.\d+).*", a)
if m:
    f = float(m.group(1))
    if (f == 2.11):
        print("ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare part of a string, you can always slice it with the syntax `str[start_index: end_index]` and then compare the slice. Please note the `start_index` is inclusive and `end_index` is exclusive. For example

```py
name = "Eric Johnson"
name[0:3] #value of the slice is "Eri" no "Eric".
```

in your case, you can do

```py
if a[0:4] == "2.11":
 #stuff next
```